# Android App is crashed on returning from an app like Google Map/GPS settings

Tags: android-intent, android-actionbar

I am calling Google Maps/GPS settings from my activity via intent. Goolge Maps appliation/GPS settings runs smoothly but when I press back button, my app is crashed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit here, but if you mean to bring up the Location settings
(symbolized by the balloon type marker in Android 4.2.2 and possibly
later versions), then the following works for me:

```
ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

In my case ctx is the result of View.getContext(), probably
you can also plug in an activity (i.e., 'this' if this is in a member
function of an Activity).

HTH